# ng-valid-pattern for empty string while regExp.test("")==false

Tags: regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have `<input type="url">`, but angularJS think that the pattern is valid even if it is empty. Everything is in the demo bellow.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HyodUFGrgenhhkk9KQn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute `data-ng-required="true"`

See demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4wjiCNzs1OxgQomUxue5?p=preview

**EDIT:**

So the current version of angular (1.2.15, 1.3.beta) will NOT run the `ng-validation` regex if there is no data in the field (or an empty string).  So I can see that the `ng-validation-pattern` class is still there after clearing the existing string like you mentioned in your comment. (I'm not sure if this is a bug or is working as designed)

For your use case, what you can do is create a rule to match when both the ng-valid-pattern and the ng-valid class are on the form.

```
.ng-valid.ng-valid-pattern{
  color:green;
}
```

I updated the plunker to show this change: http://plnkr.co/edit/4wjiCNzs1OxgQomUxue5?p=preview

Comment: Sorry this don't work, try writing some text and then delete it, it will still have class ng-valid-pattern